# replace part of url within an R function

Tags: r, function, url

I want to create a function within R that will read data from any wunderground.com csv. My first step in this process is to write the code that replaces text within the URL with the desired location and dates. The url that calls monthly summary csv files is formatted as such: wunderground.com/history/airport/KISW/2016/2/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1.

Here is my attempt thus far:

```
my_function <- function(location, month) {
    url <- paste0("wunderground.com/history/airport/",'location', "/2016/", "month", "/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1")
    print(url)
```

}

When I call this function, for example:

```
my_function(location = KMSN, month = 2)
```

I get this:

```
[1] wunderground.com/history/airport/location/2016/month/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1,
```

but I was hoping it would be:

```
wunderground.com/history/airport/KMSN/2016/2/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1
```

I have also tried using gsub in the function:

```
my_function1 <- function(location, month) {
    url <- "wunderground.com/history/airport/code/2016/month/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1"
    urll <- gsub("code", "location", url)
    print(url)
}
```

but I am not having success with this either. I get:

```
[1] wunderground.com/history/airport/code/2016/month/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1
```

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

We can modify the function and use `sprintf`

```
my_function <- function(location, month) {
   url <- sprintf(paste0("wunderground.com/history/airport/",location, "/2016/%s/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1"), month)
   print(url)
 }

 my_function("KMSL", 2)
 #[1] "wunderground.com/history/airport/KMSL/2016/2/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1"
```

Or as @Tensibai suggested

```
 my_function <- function(location, month) {
    sprintf("wunderground.com/history/airport/%s/2016/%s/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1", location, month)
    }
 my_function("KMSL",2)
 #[1] "wunderground.com/history/airport/KMSL/2016/2/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1"
```

Comment: Why not using %s in place of location too and not using paste0 ? (I see no reason to mix the two methods of text formatting...)

Comment: @Tensibai I also thought so, but just kept the initial option posted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_function1 <- function(location, month) {
    url <- "wunderground.com/history/airport/code/2016/month/1/MonthlyHistory.html?format=1"
    urll <- gsub("code", "location", url)
    print(url)
}
```

Note: Your function above is working fine . but in last  print statement replace 'url' with 'urll'. also need to add 'gsub' for 'month' also.

Comment: Have you looked at the output based on your function?

Comment: thanks! geez, I'm sorry. That was a silly error. But even still, I can't get the function to work with gsub. The sprintf above does work for me.